# How do I get my menu to accept more than one option and not end?

Tags: java, loops, menu

I am pretty new to doing java so I am in need of assistance. My menu comes up and I input a number like I prompts me too but when I input the number it just ends and doesn't wait for another number how do I get my menu to accept multiple options.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Goods[] goodsArr = new Goods[10];
        int option;
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO OUR MENU");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        
        System.out.println("1.Read in Items");
        System.out.println("2.Check Reorder Level");
        System.out.println("3.Reorder items");
        
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("ENTER NUMBERS (1-3)");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        
        option=scanner.nextInt();
        
        if(option==1) {
            inventory(goodsArr);
            
            
        }else if(option==2) {
            
            checklimit(goodsArr);
        }
        
        try {
            
            scanner = new Scanner (new File("Supplier.txt"));
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String splrline = scanner.nextLine();
                String [] splrArray = splrline.split(",");
                Supplier splr = new Supplier (splrArray[0],splrArray[1],splrArray[2],Double.parseDouble (splrArray[3]));        
            }
            scanner.close();
            
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void inventory(Goods[] goodsArr) {
        
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Inventory.txt"));
            int i=0;
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String itemline = scanner.nextLine();
                String [] lineArray = itemline.split(",");
        
                Goods item = new Goods (lineArray[0],lineArray[1],lineArray[2],Double.parseDouble(lineArray[3]),Integer.parseInt(lineArray[4]),Integer.parseInt(lineArray[5]),lineArray[6],Integer.parseInt(lineArray[7]));
                goodsArr[i] = item;
                i++;
            }
            scanner.close();

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void checklimit(Goods[] goodsArr){
        int i;
        for (i=0; i <=10; i++) {
            
            String description = goodsArr[i].getDescription();
            if(description.equals("Garden")||description.equals("Tools")) {
                System.out.println(goodsArr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why does this have the `javascript` tag?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your scanner and if statements in a while loop. The while loop condition is just an example, you can substitute your own condition

```
while(true)
{
    option=scanner.nextInt();

    if(option==1) {
        inventory(goodsArr);
    
    
    }else if(option==2) {
    
        checklimit(goodsArr);
    }
}
```